# Update a field of a document in Firestore database

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am an iOS app developer. Right now, I need my app to update his/her scores in the database (Firestore) when a user tabs a button.

I only know that it is possible to add new documents to the database according to the official doc: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart#swift. But can I simply update one key-value pair within a document at a time?

For example, I have to add 10 points to the user with ID: 1234 if he/she clicks the correct button. So first of all, I need to read the data according to the unique ID, and catch his/her current points. Then put back the points plus 10.

It looks like Firestorage only allows users to upload an entire document once a time.

Swift code snippet is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [update a single or multiple fields in a document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update-data) with the `updateData` call.

To [atomically increment a numeric value](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#increment_a_numeric_value) can you can use the `FieldValue.increment` operation. From that last link comes this example:

```
washingtonRef.updateData([
    "population": FieldValue.increment(Int64(50))
])
```

This code increments the `population` field in the document by 50, and leave other fields in the document unmodified.